# Accessing Title of downloadable products in magento2 graphql

Tags: magento2, graphql, downloadable, title, downloadable-product

I am facing issue with accessing the title of downloadable products in magento2 graphql.

```
customerDownloadableProducts {
                items {
                  date
                  download_url
                  order_increment_id
                  remaining_downloads
                  status
                }
              }
```

I also want to access title of downloadable products to display. But cant find a way to do so. Please modify the above query to display title.

Comment: Please check this link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/370850/82670

Answer (score 0):

You can access the title of the downloadable product in graphql as below query.

````
  products(filter: { sku: { eq: "240-LV04" } }) {
    items {
      sku
      name
      ... on DownloadableProduct {
        links_title
        downloadable_product_links {
          title
          sample_url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

> **Try Below Code**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
type CustomerDownloadableProduct @doc(description: "Contains details about a single downloadable product.") {
    product_name: String @doc(description: "The Product Name")
    link_title: String @doc(description: "The Product Link Name")
}
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/graphql**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CustomerDownloadableGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CustomerDownloadableProducts"
                type="VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver\CustomerDownloadableProducts" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver**

**CustomerDownloadableProducts.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\DownloadableGraphQl\Model\ResourceModel\GetPurchasedDownloadableProducts;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\GraphQl\Model\Query\ContextInterface;
use Magento\CustomerDownloadableGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CustomerDownloadableProducts as ParentClass;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 *
 * Returns available downloadable products for customer
 */
class CustomerDownloadableProducts extends ParentClass
{
    /**
     * @var GetPurchasedDownloadableProducts
     */
    private $getPurchasedDownloadableProducts;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    private $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param GetPurchasedDownloadableProducts $getPurchasedDownloadableProducts
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        GetPurchasedDownloadableProducts $getPurchasedDownloadableProducts,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->getPurchasedDownloadableProducts = $getPurchasedDownloadableProducts;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct(
            $this->getPurchasedDownloadableProducts,
            $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder
        );
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        /** @var ContextInterface $context */
        if (false === $context->getExtensionAttributes()->getIsCustomer()) {
            throw new GraphQlAuthorizationException(__('The current customer isn\'t authorized.'));
        }

        $purchasedProducts = $this->getPurchasedDownloadableProducts->execute($context->getUserId());
        $productsData = [];

        /* The fields names are hardcoded since there's no existing name reference in the code */
        foreach ($purchasedProducts as $purchasedProduct) {
            if ($purchasedProduct['number_of_downloads_bought']) {
                $remainingDownloads = $purchasedProduct['number_of_downloads_bought'] -
                    $purchasedProduct['number_of_downloads_used'];
            } else {
                $remainingDownloads = __('Unlimited');
            }

            $productsData[] = [
                'product_name' => $purchasedProduct['product_name'],
                'link_title' => $purchasedProduct['link_title'],
                'order_increment_id' => $purchasedProduct['order_increment_id'],
                'date' => $purchasedProduct['created_at'],
                'status' => $purchasedProduct['status'],
                'download_url' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'downloadable/download/link',
                    ['id' => $purchasedProduct['link_hash'], '_secure' => true]
                ),
                'remaining_downloads' => $remainingDownloads
            ];
        }

        return ['items' => $productsData];
    }
}
```

**Query:**

```
{
  customerDownloadableProducts {
    items {
      product_name
      link_title
      date
      download_url
      order_increment_id
      remaining_downloads
      status
    }
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**Note: Before running the updated query above, please execute the Magento upgrade command.**